# I would like to retrieve the words between an amount and the first word in uppercase with a regex

Tags: regex

I'm currently working with regular expressions. I know how to retrieve the euro amount with a regex:

```
r'[+-]?(?:[0-9]*[,])?[0-9]+'
```

I also know how to retrieve the word with CAPITAL letters:

```
r'\b[A-Z]+(?:\s+[A-Z]+)*\b'
```

But I don't seem to get the following to work. Retrieve the words between the euro amount and the first WORD in Capital. For example, if I have the following sentence:

```
€10,95 Hello how are you doing? good or, bad? WORD
```

I want to retrieve: "Hello how are you doing? good or, bad?"

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Put `(.+?)` between the two patterns. That capture group will capture the words in between.

Comment: `re.search(r'\d*,?\d+\s*(.*?)\s*\b[A-Z]+\b', text).group(1)`? See https://regex101.com/r/MpCckx/3

Comment: How do you define "*word*"? Are you including punctuation? What about special characters, digits?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

```py
\d*,?\d+\s*(.*?)\s*\b[A-Z]+\b
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/MpCckx/3). *Details*:

- `\d*` - zero or more digits
- `,?` - an optional `,`
- `\d+` - one or more digits
- `\s*` - zero or more whitespaces
- `(.*?)` - Group 1: any zero or more chars other than line break chars, as few as possible
- `\s*` - zero or more whitespaces
- `\b[A-Z]+\b` - one or more uppercase ASCII letters as whole word (`\b` are word boundaries).

See the Python demo:

```py
import re
text = '€10,95 Hello how are you doing? good or, bad? WORD '
m = re.search(r'\d*,?\d+\s*(.*?)\s*\b[A-Z]+\b', text)
if m:
    print(m.group(1))
```

Answer (score 4):

You can try this expression:

```
r'(?<=\d\s).*?(?=\s[A-Z])'
```

**It uses:**

lookbehind: has to start with number and whitespace.

lookahead: has to end on an upper case character.

Comment: If you use the lookarounds, you might omit the capture group and use `.*?`

Answer (score 4):

With your shown samples, please try following regex. Written and tested in Python3x.

```
import re
text = '€10,95 Hello how are you doing? good or, bad? WORD '
val=re.search(r'€\d+(?:,\d+)?\s*(.*?)(?=\s+[A-Z])', text)
print(val.group(1))
Hello how are you doing? good or, bad?
```

[Online demo for above regex](https://regex101.com/r/5VLlXL/1)

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above regex.

```
€\d+          ##Matching € character following 1 or more digits here.
(?:,\d+)?\s*  ##In a non-capturing group matching comma followed by 1 or more digits keeping it optional followed by 0 or more spaces.
(.*?)         ##Creating 1st(and only) capturing group with lazy match here.
(?=\s+[A-Z])  ##Doing positive look ahead to make sure its followed by spaces then capital letters.
```